# Get all Contacts WHERE hidden = false... but from a JSON file

Tags: json, select

I need to get Data from a JSON file which the property "hidden" = TRUE.
In MySQL would be like:
**SELECT ALL FROM table.name WHERE hidden = true;**

But my problem is that my list is in JSON format like this:

```
[

  {
    "contactId": 1,
    "added": "2015-12-21T23:34:06",
    "companyName": "Starbucks Coffee Deutschland Ltd. & Co. KG",
    "hidden":  false
  },
  {
    "contactId": 2,
    "added": "2016-03-16T13:42:37",
    "companyName": "Google GmbH",
    "hidden":  false
  },
  {
    "contactId": 3,
    "added": "2016-01-10T13:55:03",
    "companyName": "Yahoo Inc",
    "hidden":  true
  }
]
```

and I have this method in a Controller that call ALL the Data:

```
       /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the list of contacts.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal List<Contact> Retrieve()
    {
        var filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/contact.json");

        var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        var contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contact>>(json);

        return contacts;
    }
```

After hours of googling i give up.

How do I get from a simple JSOn file all the DATA that meet a certain condition?

Answer (score 1):

By applying Linq?

```
contacts.Where(c=>c.hidden)
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)?

```
jq '.[]|select(.hidden==true)' file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

... or, with a simple loop. Read the XML content into an array, then iterate through it. If you like, you can push the desired records to a separate "result" array.